# how to insert data into the db in cakephp

Tags: database, cakephp, insert

Hi I have a for that has one field (url) and I want to insert the URL typed in the form to the DB

My function add in my controller looks like this:

```
public function add(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){

        // debug($this->Link->find('all'));//this works

        $link = $this->Link->findByUrl($this->request->data['link']['url']);
        if(empty($link)){
            //I will create the link
            $this->Link->create($this->request->data, true);//true = ignoring the ID
            $this->Link->save(null, true, array('url'));

            //null = because I ready wrote "$this->request->data" in create
            //true = I want to use VALIDATION
            //array = I choose to SAVE this field only
            echo "I've created the link";
            die($this->Link->id);
        }else {
            debug($link);
            die("The link is already in the database");
            //je dois récupérer le lien
        }

    }
```

How can I insert into the DB the links entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which version of Cake you're using, but the way this would normally work is:

- `create()` new reference
- `set()` new data
- `save()` reference

Example:

```
        $this->Link->create();
        $this->Link->set($this->request->data['link']);
        $save = $this->Link->save();
        echo $save ? "I've created the link" : "Error creating link!";
        die($this->Link->id);
```